# Unable to debug ros_controllers built from source

Tags: gazebo, moveit, c++, ros-noetic, ros-controllers

I would like to debug `joint_trajectory_controller` in `ros_controllers` package while running Gazebo and RViz through a launch file generated by MoveIt Setup Assistant:

```
roslaunch myrobot_moveit_config demo_gazebo.launch
```

If `ros_controllers` is installed as a binary, both RViz and Gazebo launch successfully and load controllers: executing a trajectory in RViz after moving the robot arm will cause Gazebo to reflect the arm moving.

Next I follow these instructions to clone and build `ros_controllers` from source, so that I can debug them:

(instructions from http://wiki.ros.org/ros_control)

```
cd ~/catkin_ws/src
wstool init
wstool merge https://raw.github.com/ros-controls/ros_control/$ROS_DISTRO-devel/ros_control.rosinstall
wstool update
rosdep install --from-paths . --ignore-src --rosdistro $ROS_DISTRO -y
catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -C ~/catkin_ws
```

If I launch Gazebo & RViz again, Gazebo Server crashes with this error just after "unpausing physics":

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
what():  Time is out of dual 32-bit range
```

The controller spawner then exits because it fails to find an instance of controller manager that was supposed to be maintained by Gazebo Server.

If I uninstall ROS, delete Catkin workspace, and then re-install every package it works again, but then I can't debug ros controllers, since it installs as a binary.

This sounds to me like a version mismatch, where the `ros_controllers` built from source are using a different version of some binary data structure, but I have no idea what it is or how to look for it. I do see that the default branch for `ros_controllers` is Noetic, which is the correct distribution I am using.

Did anyone get ros controllers built from source? I tried this same thing a few months ago and it appeared to work.

Comment: I'm skeptical that the error message is accurate. It's more likely that some required shared library .so file could not be loaded. Please show us the output from `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` at the point you are ready to do the roslaunch.

Comment: I am getting the following for `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

`~/catkin_ws/devel/lib:/opt/ros/noetic/lib:/opt/ros/noetic/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

Comment: I adjusted the launch files to start Gazebo paused, since I had the clue that it crashed just after unpausing. Attached a debugger and clicked Play in Gazebo.

Visual Studio broke into `joint_state_controller.cpp` in function `void JointStateController::starting(const ros::Time& time)`, this line:

`last_publish_time_ = time - ros::Duration(1.001/publish_rate_);`

Apparently it crashed because the "time" passed into the function had 0 seconds and `1000000` nano-seconds. It's trying to subtract `1.001 / 50` from this value which would make it negative.

Comment: All right, so I modified the code that was throwing the exception and the joint state controller successfully initializes now. I guess the work-around for this issue has been found, and we'll never know why the code was buggy.

`auto interval = ros::Duration(1.001 / publish_rate_); if (!pub_time_initialized_ && time.toSec() >= interval.toSec()) /* then initialize publish time */`

Comment: Nice work. It's amazing to me that a bug like this could be in there for so long! You should combine your 2 comments into an answer, and ideally show the code change you made. If you have the time, please open a bug report in the github repo & put a link to it in your answer.)

Comment: @Mike973 can definitely do that (I already had one PR merged), but I was hoping someone would say "oh, it's the configuration that's wrong, the software is not meant to start with near-zero time value". I guess there are no objections so I will get it fixed this weekend

Comment: *"the software is not meant to start with near-zero time value"* - Every gazebo simulation always starts with t=0; that's why it's surprising to me that this bug would not have hit a large number of users.

Comment: This line of code got changed on 2023-May-29 by commit bba197e4, but the change has not been deployed to the binary apt repo yet. That explains why the rest of us have never seen this issue, and makes it high priority to report it. If you are busy, let me know if you'd like me to create the issue on github.

Comment: I can do it this afternoon. I guess the main thing that was concerning was the precise root cause you mentioned (I didn't know if I was committing a change to a code path that was only used because I configured something wrong), but since the fix is very small & issue easy to explain it shouldn't take long.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug introduced in a recent pull request, which has not yet made it into the `apt` binary packages so it only reproduces when ros_controllers is build from source.

Created issue [#628](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/issues/628) in `ros_controllers` repo.

This bug has now been fixed in https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/pull/630